# Scrapy - Break out of loop if response.status == 404

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a loop that I am trying to break out of if the response.status of the subsequent yield Request is 404. I am iterating the page number but do not know how many pages are available.  Eventually I will hit a page that will be a 404 and I want it to break the while loop. I have it hardcoded to 40 pages, but there are more than 40 pages

```
def parse(self, response):
    cat = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    for c in cat:
        while **RESPONSE.STATUS == 200**:
            url = 'http://www.url.com/'+str(c)+'/'+str(page)+'.json'
            page += 1
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_cats)

def parse_cats(self, response):
    if response.status  == '404':
        **BREAK ABOVE LOOP**
```

I looked at Request(errback=) but am not sure if that is the correct way to go about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Scrapy based on an async network library called `twisted` - the behavior is non-blocking and asynchronous. You **cannot break the loop from a request callback**.

---

You can though have some sort of a `seen_404` flag that would be available on the spider instance. Once you see `404` status - set it to `True` and break the loop in case `self.seen_404` is `True`. This is not a reliable solution since, again, this is all asynchronous - you would not know how many iterations of the loop passed when the callback was called and `seen_404` was set to `True`. But, if, for example, you know that after a `404` page all next pages would also have `404` status - then this is probably okay:

```
def parse(self, response):
    cat = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    for c in cat:
        if self.seen_404:
            break

        url = 'http://www.url.com/'+str(c)+'/'+str(page)+'.json'
        page += 1
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_cats)

def parse_cats(self, response):
    if response.status == '404':
        self.seen_404 = True
```

---

Another option would be to **make it synchronous** by passing around a list of requests (a queue) to make inside the request itself (inside [`meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta)):

```
def parse(self, response):
    cat = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    urls = ['http://www.url.com/%s/%s.json' % (c, page) 
            for page, c in enumerate(cat)]  # if you want page to start with 1: enumerate(cat, start=1)

    url = urls.pop(0)
    yield Request(url, meta={'urls': urls}, callback=self.parse_cats)

def parse_cats(self, response):
    if response.status == '404':
        # stop crawling
        raise CloseSpider('404 found at %s' % response.url)

    urls = response.meta['urls']
    try:
        url = urls.pop(0)
    except IndexError:
        raise CloseSpider('No more urls to go')

    yield Request(url, meta={'urls': urls}, callback=self.parse_cats)
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the clarification.  I will use the self.seen_404 variable to at least stop generating new 404 requests.

I also added this to settings.py to make scrapy process the iterating requests in order.

      DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
      SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeue.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
      SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeue.FifoMemoryQueue'

Comment: @EricValente please see the update. Hope that also makes sense.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot!

Assuming it will scrape slower since we are making it synchronous?

Comment: @EricValente correct, in theory it should be slower, but depending on how much urls would you need to check until 404..

Comment: @EricValente note, I've added another edit - had missing `meta={'urls': urls}` at the bottom `yield` line.

Answer (score 0):

In Scrapy 2.4.1 by default [HttpErrorMiddleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror) will stop the spider if the `response.status` is not success